# ORM and DAO in PHP

Tags: php, orm, design-patterns, dao

I am a PHP developer and I am familiar with ORM (Doctrine and Propel), but I seldom heard about DAO. What are  the differences and relationship between ORM and DAO from PHP development perspective?

If I use Symfony to develop very large and complex projects, will that be better if I use DAO? (ORM is somehow heavy I think, but I know little about DAO)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580383/where-is-the-line-between-dal-and-orm).

Relating my question here, a DAO is basically a DAL that happens to be implemented as an object.  This means that using a DAO could be lighter than your ORMs, but isn't necessarily because it doesn't imply a maximum complexity of interface or implementation, only a minimum (that an object is used to encapsulate data access operations).

If your project is large and complex, I would tend to think an ORM is going to be better than a lighter DAO.